# Disable Markdown security preview

Tags: html, docker, markdown, preview

I would need to disable the markdown preview security programmatically: I have a VScode instance running in a Docker container and I would like to display an iFrame to users to show them some content. However right now this requires to manually select `Disable` for the Markdown security content. I would like to avoid this step, is there a way to do this (maybe in the `Dockerfile` or in `settings.json`)?

I tried looking for such a setting but could not find it.